# For files in directory, only echo filename (no path)

Tags: bash, shell

How do I go about echoing only the filename of a file if I iterate a directory with a for loop?

```
for filename in /home/user/*
do
  echo $filename
done;
```

will pull the full path with the file name. I just want the file name.

Answer (score 209, accepted):

If you want a native `bash` solution

```
for file in /home/user/*; do
  echo "${file##*/}"
done
```

The above uses **Parameter Expansion** which is native to the shell and does not require a call to an external binary such as `basename`

However, might I suggest just using `find`

```
find /home/user -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: Good answer.  For those interested in learning more about parameter expansion: http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe#substring_removal

Comment: -printf: unknown primary or operator => https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/272493/72893

Comment: echo "${file##*/}" returns an empty string

Answer (score 56):

Just use `basename`:

```
echo `basename "$filename"`
```

The quotes are needed in case $filename contains e.g. spaces.

Comment: better to use parameter expansion, requires no calls to external binaries.

Comment: Btw, `` is deprecated. Better to use `$()` like Oli did

Comment: Sorry for commenting on this old answer, but basename won't work correctly for files with space. Example: pwd output: `/test 1`, `basename $(pwd)` output: `test`. Tested on OS X and Ubuntu Server (14.04). Native bash solution, as @SiegeX recommended, is what worked for me.

Comment: @MarkoGrešak Use `basename "$(pwd)"` instead.

Comment: @YoungFrog thanks for the input, but that was 9 months ago. Also it would be better to use the variable `$PWD` instead of running the command.

Comment: @YoungFrog I commented on what I have tried and what had worked for me, giving my input if someone else is looking for similar solution. You suggested me a solution for my 9 month old problem, which I had mentioned I already solved.

Comment: if going with this approach it should be: `echo \`basename $filename\`` (no quotations around $filename)

Comment: No matter if `$()` or the deprecated backticks: Why would you use `echo` in the first place? `basename` already prints the results. `echo` may even mangle the result if you don't quote the subshell. Example: ```echo $(basename path/with\ \ spaces)``` incorrectly prints `with spaces` (only one space).

Answer (score 20):

Use `basename`:

```
echo $(basename /foo/bar/stuff)
```

Comment: Why do you use `echo`? `basename` already prints the results. `echo` may even mangle the result if you don't quote the subshell. Example: ```echo $(basename path/with\ \ spaces)``` incorrectly prints `with spaces` (only one space).

Answer (score 12):

Another approach is to use `ls` when reading the file list within a directory so as to give you what you want, i.e. "just the file name/s". As opposed to reading the full file path and then extracting the "file name" component in the body of the for loop.

Example below that follows your original:

```
for filename in $(ls /home/user/)
do
  echo $filename
done;
```

If you are running the script in the same directory as the files, then it simply becomes:

```
for filename in $(ls)
do
  echo $filename
done;
```

Comment: `ls` includes any dotfiles where `*` expansion usually does not. Also `for f in $(...) ...` fails if any filename contains whitespace unless you set IFS, may fail if any filename contains a glob char unless you set -f/-o noglob, and depending on system or shell `echo` may fail if any filename is hyphen+letter or contains backslash. OTOH just `ls -1 /path/to/dir` all by itself reliably prints each filename on a line, modulo the dotfiles difference.

Answer (score 1):

You can either use what SiegeX said above or if you aren't interested in learning/using  parameter expansion, you can use:

```
for filename in $(ls /home/user/);
do
    echo $filename
done;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want filename only :

```
for file in /home/user/*; do       
  f=$(echo "${file##*/}");
  filename=$(echo $f| cut  -d'.' -f 1); #file has extension, it return only filename
  echo $filename
done
```

for more information about `cut` command see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/cut-command-linux-examples/).