# For files in directory, ignoring folders

Tags: bash, shell

Iterating a for loop, how do I make sure it ignores outputting directories?

```
for filename in /home/user/*
do
  echo $filename
done;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As in my [previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9011264/207248) you really want to use `find`. What you're trying to do on 7-10 of lines scripting can just be done with this:

```
find /home/user -type f -printf "%f\n"
```

Comment: @JoSo thanks. Next time you could just tell me I forgot the `\n` though.

Comment: Yes, or even better, just stay with `find /home/user -type f`, or, to do what OP wants, switch to `find /home/user -not type d` ;-)

Comment: @JoSo The reason for the `-printf "%f\n` will be more apparent if you click the link in my answer to the OP's other answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
for filename in /home/user/*
do
    if [ ! -d "$filename" ]; then
        echo $filename
    fi
done
```

Or, use the `find` command:

```
find /home/user ! -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Comment: This is the correct answer (and please let me emphasize that it is <b>hard</b> to get shell interaction with `find` right)

Comment: when I use the first code portion as is, it echos `/home/user/*` instead of the contents of the folder.

Comment: @Mechaflash Then `/home/user` is empty or has only hidden files. To get the hidden files, you can use `/home/user/.*` or the `find`, though with the `find` command (as Jo So hints at) you may need to tell us how you're using it so we can help you get it right.

Comment: @Kevin the folder contains a txt and pdf file. Checked to make sure they weren't hidden. I ended up using the `find` method as it works for my needs. I'm doing exactly what the question asks for: echoing the contents of a folder minus directories.

Comment: A nice alternative is: test -d $filename && continue

Comment: @WilliamPursell Yes, but I didn't want to use the one-liner `&&`  or `||` with a beginner. You could also use `[ -d "$filename" ] || echo $filename`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `-d` operator to check whether `$filename` refers to a directory:

```
for filename in /home/user/*
do
  if [ ! -d "${filename}" ]
  then
    echo $filename
  fi
done;
```

See [test manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/test) for details and other available operators.

You can also use the [find command](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find):

```
find /home/user -not -type d -maxdepth 1
```

Answer (score 1):

find command is more suitable for what you want.

```
find /home/user -type f
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while IFS='$\n' read -r filename
   do echo "$filename"
done < <(find /home/user/ -type f -maxdepth 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a conditional statement inside the loop. Something like this (untested):

```
if [ ! -d "$filename" ]
then
// do stuff
fi
```

`-d` is true if it's a directory, and that's inverted with `!`. So it will succeed if it does exist and isn't a directory.