# could use some help on ffprobe

Tags: cmd, ffmpeg, ffprobe

I'm currently running the following command and it's giving me mostly what I need, but I would like to also have it include the file name.

```
for %%A IN (%VAR0%\*.wav) DO "C:\program files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin\ffprobe" -i "%%A" -show_entries format=duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >>output.txt
```

The above produces this:

**110.994375**

This is great, but what I would really want is something like this as I need to import this data into a db for further processing.  I need to know which file the 110.9943765 came from.

**recording1.wav, 110.994375**

Thanks,

Steven

Comment: tie the numeric val in stdout to the input to ffprobe by doing the io INSIDE the loop to 'out%%A' . Then do another loop which cats the fileName with the file's content .... outRecrd1.wav  ,  110.994375  is on a line by itself   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011233/for-files-in-directory-only-echo-filename-no-path

Answer (score 1):

All you need is to add the filename key as well.

```
ffprobe -i "%%A" -show_entries format=filename,duration -v quiet -of csv="p=0" >>output.txt
```