# for loop in Bash to call Java.jar

Tags: bash, macos

Major caveat is that I am a complete bash and java ignoramus...
I have a jar file that is used to process an image. What I would like to now use a for loop to iterate over multiple images in a folder using a mac terminal bash script. The .jar call is:

```
java -Xms12288m -jar DeconvolutionLab_2.jar Run -image file /myimagedirectory/ -psf file /thisfilestaysconstant/ -algorithm TRIF 0.2 -out stack float "string_of_output_file_name" -path home
```

I've tried

```
for f in /Users/myimagedirectory/; do java -Xms12288m -jar DeconvolutionLab_2.jar Run -image file $f -psf file /thisfilestaysconstant/ -algorithm TRIF 0.2 -out stack float mi$f -path home
```

But nothing runs...

Comment: Your question is not about Java, so you should not be tagging it with [tag:java].

Comment: "`for f in /Users/myimagedirectory/;`" is looping over exactly 1 thing - that directory, not the files in the directory.

Comment: You mean `for f in /Users/myimagedirectory/*`, surely?

Comment: BTW, consider running `set -x` to actually log what your shell is doing (or starting your script with `bash -x yourscript`).

Comment: Also, use `"${f}"` and `"mi${f}"`, rather than `$f` and `mi$f`, just in case the filename has a space in it.

Comment: @AndyTurner, the quotes are needed to fix the whitespace case; the curly braces are not.

Comment: Thanks to all, Yes, /myimagedirectory/* and "${f}" were the keys for figuring it out!

Comment: @CharlesDuffy not necessary in this case (it would be if it were `$f` followed by `mi`, of course); but I find it makes it more readable. To each his own.

Comment: One last comment/question - All of this is working great, but I'm having some difficulty with my -out file, in my example it's "string_of_output_file_name". I'd like it to my the same filename as my input, or "f", but I'm getting the entire path instead of the filename. Would something like ${f##*/} work? This is based off another example I saw here (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011233/for-files-in-directory-only-echo-filename-no-path)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`for f in /Users/myimagedirectory/` won't iterate over all of the files in the directory, it'll only perform one iteration in which `$f` is set to `/Users/myimagedirectory/`.

To iterate over all of the files in that directory, use this:

```
for f in /Users/myimagedirectory/*; do
    # run your command with "$f"
done
```

The * wildcard in the expression will match all files in `/Users/myimagedirectory/`.